# Access denied error comes in magento admin systm/configuration page

Tags: magento

This question is asked by many more and answer is available, but no amswer is usefull to me, my admin works perfectly but suddenly access denied error comes in configuration page, i have not installed any module or extension, i have login/logout,clear cache, clear session all i do which is available, admin permission is set to all,i have no idea why this happen, so plz help me

Comment: Take a look in your `var/logs` directory and `var/reports` directory to see if there any logs of this access denied error. I would also tail -f apache's logs.

Comment: there is no log created for this acess denied error related issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have give custom permission and access denied error is gone